# supprt for rtl of highchart breadcrumb

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I have a treemap with 3 level that after click on section it drilldown to show just that section,is there any rtl support for highchart treemap bread crumb after drilldown

for example:(alin:right)

------------------------------- level2/level1

Comment: Do you mean [position](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.breadcrumbs.position) of breadcrumbs button?

Comment: assume we have  (level1/level2), in rtl it must be in reverse order with align right:
------------------------------level2/level1

Comment: Option to support rtl langue for breadcrumbs is not yet available, you can report this on our GitHub page, and we will manage.this.https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose